# How to convert list to dict

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have list `["a","b","c", "d"]`. I want to concert it to dict where key is position every values in list and value is value of list. In output I should get something like this:

```
{
'0' : 'a',
'1' : 'b',
'2' : 'c',
'3' : 'd'
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `enumerate()` to obtain the index of every element of the list and `dict()` to convert it to dictionary.

```
print(dict(enumerate(["a","b","c", "d"])))
```

Answer (score 1):

use dictionary comprehension.

```
>>> a = ["a","b","c", "d"]
>>> {i: j for i,j in enumerate(a)}
{0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'd'}
```

[enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate)

Answer (score -3):

I think you should create a dict and then make it:

```
{'0' : list[0], '1' : list[1], '2' : list[2],'3' : list[3]}
```

because I don't think you can convert a list to a dict in any other way

Comment: but there are ways -))

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't realize